# GCM push notifications doesn't always work

Tags: c#, android, cordova, push-notification

I build a mobile app using phonegap where users can create and share items. Part of the process is sending a push notification to 1-3 friends. For some reason sometimes all friends receive the notification, sometimes only some of the them and sometimes no one gets it.
Here is the code I am using (in c#)

```
string stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", deviceIds);

                string GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyDqwXXXXXXXXXXXXXHfbyqiA";
                var SENDER_ID = "604XXXXXXX98";
                var value = message;
                WebRequest tRequest;
                tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                //tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

                //string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.title=" + title + "&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + stringregIds + "";
                string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : " + "\"" + value + "\",\"time\": " + "\"" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\"},\"registration_ids\":[\"" + stringregIds + "\"]}";

                //Console.WriteLine(postData);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

                dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


                tReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                tResponse.Close();
```

Do you have any idea what might be the problem?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try increase `time_to_live`

Comment: @BNK - I tried to set it to maximum and also to 0. None of them worked. Anything else....?